# IllegalLocationConstraintException with Terraform state migration to AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform

I think this question is not entirely related to the migration mechanism, but rather how Terraform is configured on my dev machine.

I am in a learning path for Terraform certification even if I am not a devops guy and what I am trying to achieve is move the state file from local to AWS S3 and Dynanmodb.

this is what I have in main.tf:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "5.21.0"
      configuration_aliases = [ aws.myalias ]
    }
  }

  backend "s3" {
    bucket = "mybucket"
    key    = "terraform/notebook"
    dynamodb_table = "terraform-state"
    region = "eu-south-1"
    profile = "terraform"
  }

}
```

And this is what I have in provider.tf

```
provider "aws" {
  alias = "myalias"
  region = var.aws-region
  profile = "terraform"
}
```

When I run the following command

```
TF_LOG=debug terraform init -migrate-state
```

I get the output:

```
│ Error: Error loading state:
│     IllegalLocationConstraintException: The us-west-1 location constraint is incompatible for the region specific endpoint this request was sent to.
│   status code: 400, request id: ZKB1MZM94T4HVW51, host id: 6W/hsaWGgr8xRtgZvD+zNqoVykeaxFHB5ibzGk6Vd5LItrr7ObHu+uRx1RQdGqGsEtEunOHFOsY=
```

It says `us-west-1` !!

Looking at the log output I have noticed that two credential calls have been made at the beginning:

```
2023-10-18T11:44:23.685+0200 [DEBUG] [aws-sdk-go] <GetCallerIdentityResponse xmlns="https://sts.amazonaws.com/doc/2011-06-15/">
  <GetCallerIdentityResult>
    <Arn>arn:aws:iam::999999999:user/terraform-user/Arn>
    <UserId>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</UserId>
    <Account>9999999999</Account>
  </GetCallerIdentityResult>
  <ResponseMetadata>
    <RequestId>........</RequestId>
  </ResponseMetadata>
</GetCallerIdentityResponse>

2023-10-18T11:44:23.735+0200 [DEBUG] [aws-sdk-go] <GetCallerIdentityResponse xmlns="https://sts.amazonaws.com/doc/2011-06-15/">
  <GetCallerIdentityResult>
    <Arn>arn:aws:iam::999999999:user/my-other-user</Arn>
    <UserId>XXXXXXXXXXXXXX</UserId>
    <Account>999999999</Account>
  </GetCallerIdentityResult>
  <ResponseMetadata>
    <RequestId>........</RequestId>
  </ResponseMetadata>
</GetCallerIdentityResponse>
```

`terraform-user` is what I am using for resources creation it's working fine and it's what I want to use for everything related to Terraform (at least while I am learning). But why another call for `my-other-user` which is the default user of the `aws cli` configured on my local machine, which has infact us-west-1 as default location.

Then I see that two following identical calls are made by Terraform, one for `terraform-user` and the other for `my-other-user`:

```
2023-10-18T11:44:23.861+0200 [DEBUG] [aws-sdk-go] DEBUG: Response s3/ListObjects Details:
---[ RESPONSE ]--------------------------------------
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/xml
Date: Wed, 18 Oct 2023 09:44:24 GMT
Server: AmazonS3
X-Amz-Bucket-Region: eu-south-1
X-Amz-Id-2: xxxxxxxxxxxx
X-Amz-Request-Id: kkkkkkkkkkkk

2023-10-18T11:44:23.906+0200 [DEBUG] [aws-sdk-go] DEBUG: Response s3/ListObjects Details:
---[ RESPONSE ]--------------------------------------
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/xml
Date: Wed, 18 Oct 2023 09:44:23 GMT
Server: AmazonS3
X-Amz-Bucket-Region: us-west-1
X-Amz-Id-2: yyyyyyyyy
X-Amz-Request-Id: zzzzzzzzzz
```

And it is right because such bucket doesn't exist in us-west-1, but this is causing the whole migration to fail.
What am I doing wrong for Terraform calling two times the same operation ?

Comment: What is the value of `region = var.aws-region`?

Comment: it's eu-south-1

Comment: And you have only one provider block defined? Also, I don't think using `configuration_aliases` has any effect here. You might as well try dropping that and `alias = "myalias"` from the `provider` block.